# getting a format string is not a string literal

Tags: java, android, c, busybox

I am trying to fix a compile issue that I am getting with android N and busybox.

```
error: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Werror,-Wformat-security]
bb_perror_msg_and_die("vfork"+1);
```

This is the method throwing the error

```
pid_t FAST_FUNC xfork(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) /* wtf? */
        bb_perror_msg_and_die("vfork"+1);
    return pid;
}
```

Comment: `"vfork"+1` isn't a string literal, why not just use `"fork"`? Or disable warnings-as-errors (IIRC, something like `-Wno-error=format-security`) or disable that warning (`-Wno-format-security`).

Comment: thanks immibis the -Wno-format-security worked and compilation finished